# Ошибка HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, ubuntu, .htaccess, apache, php7

Арендовал VPS сервер для сайта который делал аутсорс.
Требования для хоста apache>= 2.2, php 5.3 в виде модуля для apache.
Сервер ubuntu 16.04  Apache 2.4.18, PHP 7.0.32. По мануалам хоста выложил сайт все работает кроме CMS. При переходе /admin появляется ошибка 500. В логах apache и mysql нет ошибок.

файл htaccess в корне сайта имеет вид

```
# ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule \.(css|js|jpg|png|gif|ico|htc|xml|swf|jpe|jpeg|htm|html|3ds)$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^files\/.*\.php$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^files\/.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^admin\/index\.php - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

# Apache-module mode
RewriteRule ^admin\/(.*)$ admin/index.php/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L]
# CGI mode
#RewriteRule ^admin\/(.*)$ admin/index.php [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,L]

# Debug
#php_flag log_errors on
#php_value log_errors_max_len 0

php_value memory_limit 256M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value upload_max_filesize 60M
```

htaccess в папке с панелью администратора пустой.
Уже миллион сайтов перечитал , не могу найти решение.
Подскажите пожалуйста с какой стороны копать.

Eror log

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(sms3.6/cfg/admin.cfg.php) [<a href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/site/data/www/site.ru/libs/sms3.6/init.admin.php on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required 'sms3.6/cfg/admin.cfg.php' (include_path='../libs/sms3.6/admin:/var/www/site/data/www/site.ru/libs/sms3.6/common/classes') in /var/www/site/data/www/site.ru/libs/sms3.6/init.admin.php on line 18
```

Comment: А читать error.log видимо вы не научились. Вам ясно указывают на файл и строку в которой проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно добавить и заполнить `sms3.6/cfg/admin.cfg.php`, как об этом пишут в логе ошибок.